# How can I display fields from two different tables using active record of left join in codeigniter?

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter

```
function get_all_notification() { //get all notification based on the 'notification' table left join by 'membership' table

    $this->db->select()->from('notification')->join('membership','membership.membership_id = notification.notif_id','left');            $notif = $this->db->get();
    return $notif->result();
}
```

> I cannot display the fields from membership table.

Comment: use select('membership.membership_id,membership.other_names,notification.*')

Comment: @Kool-Mind You mean the query string instead of that above?

Comment: select() should be filled with column names of membership too try select('notification.*,membership.*') and let me if it works

Comment: Every recommendation comment, or answer, says the same :). I answered too with just a little longer code for easier viewing.. It's just for the eyes but cheers to everyone :)

Comment: @jackskiee does it helped you. let me know if any other suggestions

Comment: @Kool-Mind your solution worked!

Comment: kool, hurray buddy

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function get_all_notification() { //get all notification based on the 'notification' table left join by 'membership' table

    $this->db->select('*')->from('notification')->join('membership','membership.membership_id = notification.notif_id','left');
    $notif = $this->db->get();
    return $notif->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_all_notification()
{ 
    $this->db->select('n.*,m.*');
    $this->db->from('notification as n')
    $this->db->join('membership as m','m.membership_id = n.notif_id','left');
    $notif = $this->db->get();
    return $notif->result();
}
```

This is used when you want a clean code that's from top to bottom. But using your code is fine to where as the arrows are continuous. You just forgot to identify which fields to select. Also using aliases are good in selecting specific fields.

as you can see, I used n.* and m.*, this is just a wildcard to select all from the n table and m. you can you n.your_field and m.your_field when specifying what you want.

**Goodluck and have fun coding** :D